# vue.js 2 routing in vue-material

Tags: javascript, routes, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-material

I'm currently working on a web page what uses [vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) with [vue-material](http://vuematerial.io/). I made a similar menu like [this](https://codepen.io/vue-material/pen/WoZpMR).

My goal, that one of the menu item redirect the user to an another page.
I tried as a [official doc](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html) says:

```
  <md-list-item @click="$refs.sidebar.toggle(); this.$router.push('/company');">
    <md-icon>start</md-icon> <span>Starred</span>
  </md-list-item>
```

But I got a vue-warn message:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "click": "TypeError: this.$router is undefined"
```

I tried the all version: `$router.push('/company');`,`router.push('/company');`,`this.router.push('/company');` but stil does not works.

On the other hand i tried to surround the `md-list-item` with `router-link` tag but it didnt work as well.

How can I define the routing inline (in the `@click` section)?

Thx for the responses in advance!

**UPDATE:**

My `vue-route` config in `app.js`:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)
...
const routes = [];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    beforeUpdate: function() {
      console.debug('app rerendering');
      console.debug(this);
    },
    beforeCreate: function() {
      console.debug('app creating');
      console.debug(this);
    },
    router,
});
```

But the problem is the same... If I try to call this.`$router.push('/company')` I got a same error: `TypeError: this.$router is undefined`

Comment: can you post your router config?
and more important, did you add this `router` config to your `Vue` root instance?

Comment: Aaah, It shows that Im such a rookie in this vue - world. I didnt make a router config, I thought that the vue component will become an <a> link, or something like that. Can you show me what is the best practice, or can you link some tutorial?

Comment: @EvaldoBratti I updated the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your router config seems ok. The problem here is `this.` in your `@click`, there is no need (you already use `$refs` without `this` :P) .

```
<md-list-item @click="$refs.sidebar.toggle(); $router.push('/company');">
    <md-icon>start</md-icon> 
    <span>Starred</span>
</md-list-item>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tv8zg6tn/)

Comment: Ohh thanks, you are right! My last question, that why dont reload the whole page? Its just add the '/company' to the end of the url. I tried to add `location.reload();` to the click event, but it gives me an error; location is not defined, but if I call it in the browser console, it runs well..

Comment: In SPA you are hardly going to do a full reload page. The router will just change the components that are being shown to match the component that is set in the config to that url. You will not (and should not) notice a full reload, only a change of components.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier and cleaner as shown below::

```
<md-list-item to="/company">
   <md-icon>start</md-icon> 
   <span>Starred</span>
</md-list-item>
```

Comment: I don't know vue very well but will this solve the problem?  Could you throw in a note about whether this will fix what the question is asking about or is just a cleaner way of doing something that was given in the example?  It seems like it would remove the error but will it do the same stuff?